# Can't run Hello World React Native App - Missing Realm constructor

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to build a test react-native app using [these instructions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/getting-started.html).

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
cd AwesomeProject
react-native run-android
```

When I do that (on device and on emulator), I get:

> Missing Realm constructor - please ensure RealmReact framework is included!

I haven't done anything special (I haven't even touched the code yet), just trying to load the default Hello World app.

[image]

Comment: Make sure you are using latest version of node and npm

Comment: yeah, i don't think that's it. i can run other projects just fine. it's just the basic hello world app from the react-native docs.

Comment: Check out this [issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/459) on github

Comment: rnpm link realm didn't do anything for me

Comment: I think you are on windows machine probably? If yes, then it will fail there. Try `react-native link realm` command

Comment: no I'm on a mac

Comment: Ok still try to run this command and let me know. Please also tell what is your version of node and npm? I am assuming that you have installed latest react native version

Comment: react-native-cli: 1.0.0, react-native: 0.33.0, node v6.5.0, nom 3.10.3, rnpm 1.9.0. running `react-native link-realm` gives me "{ Error: Cannot find module '/Users/kevin/src/scratch/SampleProject/node_modules/realm/package.json'..."

Comment: Alright. You have got all latest stuff. One thing, may be you are doing typo.. it is `react-native link realm`, not `react-native link-realm`. If this wasn't issue, then you need to install realm manually. Run: 1. `npm install --save realm` 2. `rnpm link realm`

Comment: Did you successfully add the realm dependency or is this error coming before you adding it

Comment: I am getting the same error, and it is coming before adding this dependency, I simply need to run the newly created project.

Answer (score 2):

This can be because you have a **React Packager** terminal instance already running for some old app, and you just created a new project and ran it. You need to close old React Packager and then do

```
react-native run-ios
```

for your new project.